# How to Update/Drop a Hive Partition?

Tags: hive, hiveql

After adding a partition to an **external table** in **Hive**, how can I update/drop it?

Answer (score 188, accepted):

You can update a Hive partition by, for example:

```
ALTER TABLE logs PARTITION(year = 2012, month = 12, day = 18) 
SET LOCATION 'hdfs://user/darcy/logs/2012/12/18';
```

This command does not move the old data, nor does it delete the old data. It simply sets the partition to the new location.

To drop a partition, you can do

```
ALTER TABLE logs DROP IF EXISTS PARTITION(year = 2012, month = 12, day = 18);
```

Comment: Just FYI, for Spark SQL this will also not work to update an existing partition's location, mostly because the Spark SQL API does not support it. Also from the Hive CLI, you would need to run `use <schema>` first, otherwise it will fail with `FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. Unable to alter partition. Unable to alter partitions because table or database does not exist.` even if the table does exist.  So if the table name is `<schema>.<table>`, from the CLI you have to run `use <schema>` first before changing the partition location.

Comment: This appears to hang forever with an ORC table

Comment: I take that back, it just takes 3 minutes to drop an empty partition. Normal Hadoop performance.

Answer (score 20):

in addition, you can drop multiple partitions from one statement ([Dropping multiple partitions in Impala/Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45543396/dropping-multiple-partitions-in-impala-hive)).

Extract from above link:

```
hive> alter table t drop if exists partition (p=1),partition (p=2),partition(p=3);
Dropped the partition p=1
Dropped the partition p=2
Dropped the partition p=3
OK
```

**EDIT 1:**

Also, you can drop bulk using a condition sign (>,<,<>), for example:

```
Alter table t 
drop partition (PART_COL>1);
```

Answer (score 6):

```sql
Alter table table_name drop partition (partition_name='value');
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it - there are already other answers using other approaches. Can you explain why your's looks different?

Comment: this does not work, why does it have so many likes? -1 from me

Answer (score 3):

You may also need to make database containing table active

```
use [dbname]
```

otherwise you may get error (even if you specify database i.e. dbname.table )

> FAILED Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. Unable to alter partition. Unable to alter partitions because table or database does not exist.

Comment: Any idea if there's a workaround for this for doing the same operation in `spark.sql()`, which only supports one command at a time (and `spark.sql("use <schema>")` followed by `spark.sql("alter table ...")` does not work, especially for cases where you'd want to change a partition format which is not allowed in add partition.

Answer (score 2):

You can either copy files into the folder where external partition is located or use

`INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE tablename1 PARTITION (partcol1=val1, partcol2=val2...)...`

statement.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from other answers in this post, for `multiple partitions`, do this

```
ALTER TABLE database.table_name DROP PARTITION (partition_column >= value);
```

Example for database `employee` with table name `accounts`, and partition column `event_date`, we do:-

```
ALTER TABLE employee.accounts DROP PARTITION (event_date>='2023-02-25');
```

This will drop all partitions from 25th Feb 2023 to the current date.