# Create Hive external table with partition WITHOUT column name in the path?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I need to create an external table for an read only existed folder structure.

The original hive table has partitions like year, month and day. Their files store in path in this way `HDFS_PATH/2016/10/04/`

But when I create an external table in hive, it always store to path like `HDFS_PATH/year=2016/month=10/day=04/`

Although I can change 1 partition location like in this link [How to Update/Drop a Hive Partition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13815179/how-to-update-drop-a-hive-partition)
, but I have to set location for each partition combination.

Is there a simpler way to set it once and for all?

Comment: Just to be clear: are you looking for a way to create one specific table with one specific folder structure for Year/Month/Day? Or do you need a generic solution that would also work for partitions like Quarter, or PostalCode?

Comment: create only 1 table, but it has many partitions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thought it best to answer your question since the other answers don't explain.

The only way to use dynamic partitioning (not listing out every partition and adding individually) is to use the "Hive style" partitioning you mentioned in the format: `HDFS_PATH/year=2016/month=10/day=04/`.

While HCatalog has support for custom paths, Hive itself does not and there is an -[open ticket tracking this feature here.](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-8053)

Until this ticket is resolved, you have to use the "Hive style" format you mentioned (and mentioned in this ticket) or manually add all partitions yourself using the `ALTER TABLE` command. Once this ticket is resolved, then `MSCK REPAIR TABLE` could work like you want.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late:

```
 alter table my_table add partition (year='2017',month='07',day='10', hour='10') location '2017/07/10/10';
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but then I have to enumerate all combinations of all partitions, which is what I tried to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this dinamically by setting: `set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;` or you can just do `msck repair table table_name` that will partition your data.

Comment: it doesn't solve my requirement `without column name in path`

Comment: I see, then I think you have to do set all partition combination, but you can write a scripts that increments day bay day adding partition. In this way, you can add or drop partition automatically.