# What is the best way to update partitions?

Tags: hadoop, hive, amazon-athena

I want to update partitions using below code.

```
msck repair table_name
```

(I can't use the other options such as refresh statement like that)

But I don't know the best way to update partitions.

1) I run that code every minutes.

2) I select the partitions using show command then if partitions doesn't exists then run that code.

```
show partitions table_name
```

Which is the best way to update partition (the other option is okay), so there is no limitation to search data ?

Would you give me an advice?

Comment: Possible duplicate:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13815179/how-to-update-drop-a-hive-partition

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But I want to know how to use msck repair command properly. The result of answer is same so it looks like similar but a little bit different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Command `msck repair table_name` is expensive one. You can use command `ADD PARTITION`.

E.g.

```
ALTER TABLE tblName ADD PARTITION (dt='2008-08-08', country='us') location '/path/to/us/part080808'
```

If you don't want to check if partitions exists or not, simply use `IF NOT EXISTS`. It will create partition if not exists.

```
ALTER TABLE tblName ADD IF NOT EXISTS PARTITION (dt='2008-08-08', country='us') location '/path/to/us/part080808'
```

Comment: Thank you! I use it than msck repair command. I have a question. What do you mean of "msck repair table_name expensive on"? I'm not familiar with hive. So would you give me some more explanation?

Comment: @Bethlee `msck` standsd for `metastore check`. So hive tries to validate the data on HDFS with the data in the metastore. If it sees any discrepancies in ,say, the partitions, it will try to add those partition all at once or one by one.

Comment: @philantrovert Thank you so much for explaining it!

Answer (score 0):

another option would also be

```
ALTER TABLE tblName UPDATE PARTITIONS;
```

Comment: Maybe the syntax changed, now it seems to be:
`ALTER TABLE tblName RECOVER PARTITIONS;`