# Dropping multiple partitions in Impala/Hive

Tags: sql, hive, hdfs, partitioning, impala

1- I'm trying to delete multiple partitions at once, but struggling to do it with either Impala or Hive. I tried the following query, with and without `'`:

`ALTER TABLE cz_prd_corrti_st.s1mme_transstats_info DROP IF EXISTS
 PARTITION (pr_load_time='20170701000317')
 PARTITION (pr_load_time='20170701000831')`

The error I'm getting is as follow:

> AnalysisException:
>   Syntax error in line 3: PARTITION (pr_load_time='20170701000831') ^
>   Encountered: PARTITION Expected: CACHED, LOCATION, PURGE, SET,
>   UNCACHED CAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error

The partition column is bigint type, query for deleting only one partition works as expected:

```
ALTER TABLE cz_prd_corrti_st.s1mme_transstats_info DROP IF EXISTS
PARTITION   (pr_load_time='20170701000317')
```

2- Is it a good practice delete the hdfs data first and then drop the partitions in Impala/Hive, or is it supposed to be done vice versa?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### 1.

Your syntax is wrong.
In the DROP command the partitions should be separated by commas.

**Demo**

```
hive> create table t (i int) partitioned by (p int);
OK

hive> alter table t add partition (p=1) partition(p=2) partition(p=3) partition(p=4) partition(p=5);
OK

hive> show partitions t;
OK
partition
p=1
p=2
p=3
p=4
p=5

hive> alter table t drop if exists partition (p=1),partition (p=2),partition(p=3);
Dropped the partition p=1
Dropped the partition p=2
Dropped the partition p=3
OK

hive> show partitions t;
OK
partition
p=4
p=5
```

#### 2.

You can drop a range.

**Demo**

```
hive> create table t (i int) partitioned by (p int);
OK

hive> alter table t add partition (p=1) partition(p=2) partition(p=3) partition(p=4) partition(p=5);
OK

hive> show partitions t;
OK
partition
p=1
p=2
p=3
p=4
p=5

hive> alter table t drop if exists partition (p<=3);
Dropped the partition p=1
Dropped the partition p=2
Dropped the partition p=3
OK

hive> show partitions t;
OK
partition
p=4
p=5
```

Comment: You're indeed correct, Hive works with mentioned syntax. Havent found solution for Impala yet.

Comment: Unfortunately comparators in partition predicate (`partition (p<=3)`) do not work in Spark SQL yet, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-14922

Comment: The second demo works with Impala 2.8+. See https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_alter_table.html where it says "In Impala 2.8 and higher, the expression for the partition clause with a DROP or SET operation can include comparison operators such as <, IN, or BETWEEN, and Boolean operators such as AND and OR."