# How to delete the older data in partitioned Hive Table?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I need to delete the hive table data ,older than 4 years 
Table is partitioned by year , month and date

Can you please help me on this ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45543396/dropping-multiple-partitions-in-impala-hive

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dropping multiple partitions in Impala/Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45543396/dropping-multiple-partitions-in-impala-hive)

Comment: I need a insert overwrite HQL , Since table partitioned at day level , its very difficult to found and delete those partions , Please help on insert overwrite HQL,
Table had timestamp column

Comment: Nothing difficult, read this answer please: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56646879/2700344